# mongokit not authenticating mongodb replicaset, showing each connection as operation error

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, mongokit

while using it in application it shows operation error.. while readWrite, dbOwner and dbAdmin role was defined for the users
it shows

OperationFailure: database error: not authorized for query on database.
pymongo version: 2.6.3
django-mongokit : 0.2.6
mongokit - 0.9.1 
mongodb version v2.6.7

while i provided read-write and dbowner role for the user that i m using in application

seems a problem with mongokit.

Comment: Please give us more information. Show us the code you are using to authenticate. The most common reason for problems like this is that you are not authenticating to the database where the user was defined.

Comment: I put this in django settings.py like this

'mongodb': {
'ENGINE': 'django_mongokit.mongodb',
'NAME': 'delhivery_db',
'USER': '********',
'PASSWORD': '*******',
'HOST': '10.***.***.***',
'PORT': 27017,
},

Comment: What database does that user live in? Is it `delivery_db`? Did you misspell `delivery_db` as `delhivery_db`?

Comment: no, not misspelled. user lives in delhivery_db database.